# AsyncTask not executing onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

i am working on an AsyncTask but after the doInBackground is completed onPostExecute doesnt gets called.

Here's my AsyncTask class

```
  public class GetServerData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String>{

Context con;
ArrayList<Items> data;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
String IMAGE_PREFIX, cat_id;

public GetServerData(Context con, ArrayList<Items> data, ListViewAdapter adapter, String cat_id){
    this.con = con;
    this.data = data;
    this.adapter = adapter;
    IMAGE_PREFIX =  con.getResources().getString(R.string.web_image_prefix);
    this.cat_id = cat_id;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String url = (String) arg0[0];


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = null;


    if (!(((Activity) con) instanceof MainActivity)){

        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit", (String) arg0[1]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cat_id", cat_id));

    }else if (((Activity) con) instanceof MainActivity){
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit", (String) arg0[1]));
    }

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }catch (Exception e){;
        }

    String result = null;

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        try {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return result;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(con, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

and further more this is how i am executing the task

```
new GetServerData(this, data, adapter, CPATH).execute(URL, ""+current_limit);
```

the doInBackground method runs perfectly and does gets data as it should. But i need to post process the data in onPostExecute. But it doesnt gets called. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: ots not showing toats? put debug point there

Comment: I think you are getting some exceptions some where and because you are catching every exceptions, the app is not crashing..

Comment: Apart from you issue, do not show toast messages from doInBackground.

Comment: Got it thanks :) 

But still any help on the issue please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved in a very unexpected way. Restarting eclipse fixed the problem as i looked into in the Eclipse wasn't building the project properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying toast messages in doInbackground, thats a violation of async task all ui related stuff should go in postExecute.

Please remove these lines.

Comment: That's true, I also pointed it out in the comment but if exceptions are not thrown this can't be the reason for onPostExecute() not being executed.

Comment: I've commented out all the Toast lines from doInBackground. But the problem still persists onPostExecute is still not getting called. i"ve called 

new GetServerData(this, data, adapter, CPATH).execute(URL, ""+current_limit);

this line from onCreate() method of the Activity

Comment: What is current_limit, are u cAlling this task from the main UI

Comment: yeah i'm calling it from the onCreate of the Activity.

and current limit is just a String here.

Answer (score 1):

```
}catch (Exception e){
   Toast.makeText(con, "Unable to fetch data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The Toast.makeText in the last catch block is throwing the exception. I think this makes it pretty clear that you should not be attempting to display toasts from a background thread.

You should be able to see the stack trace for this in logcat.

Comment: I've removed all the toasts in the code. But exceptions were not an issue as the method doInBackground executed successfully with no errors. But still onPostExecute wasn't getting called.